# How to remove any jQuery action bound to a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my wordpress website i have a calendar page managed by a plugin installed which has some basic links in it `<a class="mylink" href="http://myurl.com">Some text</a>`.

Somewhere in that plugin there is some Javascript code that once the user clicks on one of those links triggers an AJAX call. Well, I don't want this to happen. And, of course, i don't want to edit the plugin core files.

What i want to do is to simply create a script that removes any action bound to those links so that once the user clicks on one of those links nothing happens.
So, i tried with jQuery methods `preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()`, but none of them worked.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.mylink', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //do the stuff i want here
});
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Add a "return false;" at the end

Comment: Nothing changes...

Comment: Try `$('.mylink').off('click')` after you instantiate the plugin.

Comment: are you sure you're adding the callbacks before the plugin?

Comment: If the plugin binds the click with some namespace, such as $(el).on('click.namespace',function(){}). You will need to know that click.namespace to unbind it.

Answer (score 2):

Much like the `on()` function can be used to wire up events, you can use the [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to remove the event handlers :

```
$(document).off('click','.mylink');
```

You'll just need to ensure that this is performed after your initial event handler was created.

Comment: I've put that code at the end of the page, before </body>, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe you may find helpful to look at the page? http://autodromodifranciacorta.it/calendario/2016-04/
The links are "<< marzo" and "maggio >>" at the bottom of the page

Comment: Based on the mark-up within your page, it looks like your `<a>` tags are actually beneath a section in your plugin, so the previous suggestion might not be targeting them properly. I suppose you could try something like `$('#tribe-events-footer a').off('click');` or `$(document).off('click',#tribe-events-footer a');` to see if either of those work.

Comment: @AlbertoFontana If you disable the click events. How do you plan on switching to the next calendar? The entire link would be disabled.

Comment: @Hoyen this way: `window.location.href = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");`. I don't load the calendar on the page, but i load the new one. The reason is because there is a bug in the translation plugin and this is the easiest way to fix it.

Comment: @RionWilliams none of them is working :(

Comment: @AlbertoFontana But you are disabling the click event and thus you won't be able to trigger any JavaScript code either.

Comment: @Hoyen so how do i unbind the existing click events and then apply a new one?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're just adding another handler for the click event, not replacing the original handler(s). You need to unbind click events on those links. The code to do this:

```
jQuery('a.mylink').unbind('click')
```